# Strange characters from a device usb using inputstream bytes[] java

Tags: java, serial-port, byte, inputstream

i have to get some of data that the pc receives via device usb connected.
I get to connect to the serial port(with javacomm librarys) and receive data every two minutes that sends the device. These data, store them in a byte[] and show it to InputStream something like this:

> `try {
>        int count = inputStream.available();
>        byte[] bs = new byte[count];
>        System.out.print(inputStream.read(bs));//also with (bs,0,count)..
>
>   } catch (IOException e) {  }`

But this shows always 0 (zero). I have tried with others methods eg directly printing de byte[] and the output is " [B@e35bb7  " i don't know what is this...

> `try {
>       System.out.println(bs); 
>   } catch (IOException e) { }`

I tried to convert it to String:

> `try {
>       String me=bs.toString();
>       String txtohex=String.format("%04x", new BigInteger(1, me.getBytes("UTF-8")));
>       System.out.println(txtohex);//returns 5b424031633765326461
>
>      } catch (IOException e) {  }`

or :

`try {

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       for (byte b : bs){
         sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));

       }
       System.out.println(sb.toString());//returns C4 3C 00 A0 00 00 00 00 00 
   } catch (IOException e) {  }`

But this is wrong because I'm converting string [B@e35bb7. From device I have to get a very long either binary or hexadecimal string and this I am getting not is. What can I do more to receive exactly what the device sends me?

Comment: JavaDoc -> if the method available() returns 0, should be overriden in a subclass, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `new String(btye[])` instead of `toString()` to get string from byte array.

Comment: This prints me other strange characters as a D, A, C... uppercase or a white square.

Comment: `byte[] bs = new byte[count];`
 `inputStream.read(bs));` then `System.out.println(new String(bs))`.

Comment: You can print value of count to know the count of bytes you are reading.Try to make make sure you are getting data.

Comment: :( this count print 0 is it done so? `int count = inputStream.available();`

Comment: It means your inputStream is not getting data.

Comment: But if i make `readBuffer = new byte[50];` then `System.out.println(new String(readBuffer));` this tells me i receive 4 bytes and print 1 strange character... with default value on byte[50]

Comment: Make sure the reading methods being used are correct and for printing message correctly the byte[] size should be the exactly size of the message read.

Comment: My problem is that receives an InputStream serial port but not its contents in bytes. I reviewed my code and  should receive some contents in bytes only declaring `inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();` and `inputStream.available()` it should return de number of bytes but returns 0 :(